# Null value in From property in Ms Exchange Server Webservices

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

This code works except that the From property is returned as blank.  No amount of messing around with PropertySets seems to fix it.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection sfc = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
sfc.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, true));
ItemView view = new ItemView(1000);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sfc, view);


foreach (EmailMessage i in findResults)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Received: " + i.DateTimeReceived.ToString() + " From: " + i.From + " Subject: " + i.Subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566107%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx): "The FindItem operation returns only the first 512 bytes of any streamable property. For Unicode, it returns the first 255 characters by using a null-terminated Unicode string. It does not return any of the message body formats or the recipient lists. FindItem will return a recipient summary. You can use the [GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565934%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) operation to get the details of an item.
FindItem returns only the Name (EmailAddressType) element and does not return the EmailAddress (NonEmptyStringType) element in the Mailbox element for the following fields:
The from field for messages
The Sender field for messages
The organizer field for calendar items"

See also [this Stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669794/how-to-get-email-body-receipt-sender-and-cc-info-using-ews)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what I really needed is this:

Console.WriteLine("From: " + i.From.Name);